# Create (mathematical) function from set of predefined values

Tags: excel, math

I want to create an excel table that will help me when estimating implementation times for tasks that I am given. To do so, I derived 4 categories in which I individually rate the task from 1 to 10.

Those are: *Complexity of system* (simple scripts or entire business systems), *State of requirements* (well defined or very soft), *Knowledge about system* (how much I know about the system and the code base) and *Plan for implementation* (do I know what to do or don't I have any plan what to do or where to start).

After rating each task in these categories, I want to have a resulting *factor* of how expensive and how long the task will likely take, as a **very rough estimate** that I can tell my bosses.

---

#### What I thought about doing

I thought to create a function where I define the inputs and then get the result in form of a number, see:

```
|  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  | Result |
|  1  |  1  |  1  |  1  |  160   |
|  5  |  5  |  5  |  5  |  80    |
|  10 |  10 |  10 |  10 |  2     |
```

And I want to create a function that, when given `a, b, c, d` will produce the results above for the extreme cases (max, min, avg) and of course any values (`float`) in between.

How can I go about doing this? I imagine this is some form of polynomial problem, but how can I actually create the function that creates these results?

I have tasks like this often, so it would be cool to have a sort of pattern to follow whenever I need to create such functions for any amount of parameters and results needed.

I tried using wolfram alphas `interpolate polynomial` command for this, but the result is just a mess of extremely large fractions...

How can I create this function properly with reasonable results?

---

While writing this edit, I realize this may be better suited over at programmers.SE - If no one answers here, I will move the question there.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for?  You want to define a function `f(a,b,c,d)` such that `f(1,1,1,1) = 160)`, `f(5,5,5,5) = 80`, and `f(10,10,10,10) = 2`?  That's easily doable.  What do you mean by `max`, `min`, and `avg` though?  Polynomials can never have both a max and a min, and average doesn't make much sense for them (ignoring constant polynomials).

Anyways, the standard way to produce such a polynomial is via Lagrange interpolation, which will result in a bunch of "messy" fractions, and is likely the same as what WolframAlpha is doing.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm searching for. The thing is that the "messy fractions" make it really hard for me to implement it. And I only need this fixed range (from 1 to 10), so I was thinking that could make it easier, because I don't want values outside of that... mix/max/avg referred to the input values, not the result values

Comment: Does your function need to be a polynomial?  If not, does it even need to be differentiable?  Why are the messy fractions hard to implement?  Also, 5 is not the average of 1 and 10.

Comment: Haha okay - no it doesn't - I just want to be able to set the parameters, get the results within the boundaries i defined. No differentiation is necessary. I need to implement this function as a caluclated field in EXCEL, which makes it quite hard to have large fractions

Comment: Your problem is severely underdetermined. For example, you only give cases where a=b=c=d. What should happen if they are not equal? Do you want a symmetric solution, where renaming parameters changes nothing? Would you accept a solution which interpolates on a and throws away b, c, d? It might help if you could give some details about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I added a paragraph about what I want to do with this function.

Comment: "Interpolation" is the general term, see [questions/tagged/interpolation+excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/interpolation+excel) on SO. With 3 variables e.g. lat long altitude you have say temperature at a few points (Messstationen) over a country and want to interpolate, estimate, temperature at some points in between. Anyway, 1) avoid polynomials and 2) please put up a better example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough data as it is. The simplest formula which takes into account all your four [explanatory variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_and_independent_variables#Independent_variable) would be linear:

```
x0 + x1*a + x2*b + x3*c + x4*d
```

If you formulate a set of equations for this, you have three equations but five unknowns, which means that you don't have a unique solution. On the other hand, the data points which you did provide are proof of the fact that the relation between scores and time is not exactly linear. So you might have to look at some family of functions which is even more complex, and therefore has even more parameters to tune. While it would be easy to tune parameters to match the input, that choice would be pretty arbitrary, and therefore without predictive power.

So while your system of four distinct scores might be useful in the long run, I'd not use that at the moment. I'd suggest you collect some more data points, see how long a given task actually did take you, and only use that fine-grained a model once you have enough data points to fit all of its parameters.

In the meantime, aggregate all four numbers into a single number. E.g. by taking their average. Then decide on a formula to choose. E.g. a quadratic one:

```
182 - 22.9*a + 0.49*a*a
```

That's a fair fit for your requirements, and not too complex or messy. But the choice of function, i.e. a polynomial one, is still pretty arbitrary. So revisit that choice once you have more data. Note that this polynomial is almost the one [Wolfram Alpha found for your data](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=interpolate%20polynomial%20%7B%7B1%2C160%7D%2C%7B5%2C80%7D%2C%7B10%2C2%7D%7D):

```
1642/9 - 344/15*a + 22/45*a*a
```

I only converted these rational numbers to decimal notation, which I truncated pretty early on since all of this is very rough in any case.

On the whole, this question appears more suited to [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) than to [Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), in my opinion. But don't bother them unless you have sufficient data to actually fit a model.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Maybe I thought too easy on this one. I will try to gather some more information and try it on CrossValidated again later.